# What's the best Wireframing tool?

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for something similar to iPlotz or Mockup.

I've found the [Pencil Project](http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx), but it requires xulrunner-1.9 (which seems to be incompatible with xulrunner-1.9.2) in order to run as a standalone application. It can be used as a firefox plugin... but it is a bit slower.

The error on my desktop (Ubuntu 10.04) is: `Could not find compatible GRE between version 1.9.1 and 1.9.2.*`

Does anyone know other software?

**Edit**: Open-source software is preferred, and it doesn't matter whether or not it's free.

Comment: Could you explain what is wrong with Pencil?

Comment: @dv3500ea, I think he did: I've found Pencil Project, but it require xulrunner-1.9 (seem to be incompatible with xulrunner-1.9.2) to be run as a standalone application; However it can be used as a firefox plugin..but is a bit slower.

Comment: I have xulrunner-1.9.2 installed and Pencil runs fine

Comment: @dv3500ea, now im at home with ubuntu 10.10 and it works; this evening on my office desktop with ubuntu 10.04 didnt work, the error message was `Could not find compatible GRE between version 1.9.1 and 1.9.2.*`

Comment: if you cd into where you have unpacked pencil and `xulrunner application.ini`, that fixes your initial problem

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/1763/native-foss-gui-prototyping-tools and http://askubuntu.com/questions/16001/what-interface-mockup-programs-are-available

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[WireframeSketcher](http://wireframesketcher.com) is a rapid wireframing tool for Eclipse-based IDEs like Aptana, Zend Studio and the like. It also comes as a standalone version for all major platforms including Ubuntu. Give it a try.

[image: Sample WireframeSketcher mockup]

Comment: It's not free nor open source, but fully functional with some limitations.

Comment: @Hendy: i dont mynd the "free" part, is the "not opensource" i dont like much..

Comment: @DaNiel: just so you know, certain parts of WireframeSketcher are now [open-source](http://wireframesketcher.com/developers.html).

Comment: I just intalled it and I am already loving it.

Comment: Oooh this thing is bloody expensive.

Answer (score 6):

After some research, I found Dia, and it's exactly what I was looking for: simple, open and stable.

Maybe I explained my needs badly.  More than just software to design layouts, I also needed something that provided the ability to build flowcharts. I tried ArgoUML, too. It looks great, just a bit complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Balsamiq](http://balsamiq.com/). It uses Adobe Air and runs properly on Ubuntu.

Comment: Balsamiq doesnt seem to be open source.

Comment: Correct. Balsamiq isn't open source.

Comment: Shame someone marked this down - the answer came before the question was edited to express a preference for open source.  Even then, marking down software for being closed source seems pretty narrow minded (obviously assuming that was why it was marked down...).

Comment: Specially because Balsamiq seems to be a great tool.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's not so sophisticated, but you could also try Gazpacho, an UI designer.
It's in the repositories.

Answer (score 2):

As of Pencil 1.2 it runs on xulrunner 1.9.2 (I'm on Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit).

First install xulrunner 1.9.2 :

```
sudo apt-get install xulrunner-1.9.2-gnome-support
```

If you're still having problems or you're on 64-bit, run it like this:

```
xulrunner /opt/pencil/application.ini
```

Comment: I have xulrunner 1.9.2 on 11.04 and Pencil 1.2 didn't work for me.

Comment: @Jay what the error message looks like ? I've updated my answer, please try it

Comment: [code]Error: Platform version '2.0' is not compatible with
minVersion >= 1.9.1
maxVersion <= 1.9.2.*[/code]

Comment: Pencil can now be installed from the Ubuntu Software app. Pencil's package name is *pencil-snap-demo*.

Answer (score 2):

I did a bit of digging and found [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/pencil/). According to it, after you install the latest version of Firefox and Pencil (Pencil's latest version does not come in `deb` by default, so get the `rpm` and install with `alien -i <rpmname>`), edit the `application.ini` from the Pencil folder in `/usr/lib` and change the max version mentioned to the version of Firefox you have (the main release version is sufficient, e.g., 16). Then edit `usr/bin/evoluspencil`, which is nothing but a script to invoke `xulrunner`. Change `/usr/bin/xulrunner` to `/usr/bin/firefox`. Now opening Pencil from the applications menu will work just fine, and Firefox needs not be open for it to run.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @msPeachy! I have modified the answer.

Comment: Excellent! This was exactly what I needed!