# What interface mockup programs are available?

Tags: software-recommendation

Are there any interface mockup design applications for Ubuntu? I need one in order to design programs or interfaces (internet sites and more).

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/1763/native-foss-gui-prototyping-tools

Comment: It is a similar question but this is not the answer I am looking for. I need someone to recommend me a few mockup programms that are suitable for my case and maybe the best for him.

Comment: Please rephrase your question so it invites less-subjective answers. Perhaps **"What interface mockup programs are available on Ubuntu?"** would be better than "Best mockup program".

Comment: [This question](http://ui.stackexchange.com/q/831/2483) may be of interest.

Comment: If anybody else wonders where those "Basic Web Elements" - seen in the screenshot of Pencil - are in the Firefox plugin version, they currently (v1.2) only seem to be available on the standalone version.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As has  been suggested in [many other similar threads](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=pencil), [Pencil](https://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx) offers you a nice framework for prototyping and wireframing (even web stuff). And it's free.

[image]

I realise you've already said this isn't the answer you're looking for (having been linked to my question on the topic) but my scope is web development... Which is what you say you want to do. It's perfect for fleshing out page-level objects in a quick grid layout. Much more simple than a full graphics package, with various UI hints available as drag-on objects.

There's a [deb package available](https://pencil.evolus.vn/Downloads.html) for installation.

Comment: Never liked Pencil. It might just be me but I never managed to produce any decent wireframes with it, and I find it extremely unintuitive. My favorite is WireframeSketcher, a plug-in for the Eclipse Platform.

Comment: I try to run from ubuntu 64bit in console and show me that message:
"Could not find compatible GRE between version 1.9.1 and 1.9.2.*."

Comment: See my edit. It needs a launcher on newer versions of Ubuntu

Comment: Version 1.3.4 is very intuitive. I don't see yet what is missing in this soft

Comment: I downloaded the .deb package but the installation fails.
The reason was that there is an other software named pencil which I had installed.

Comment: It also works as Firefox plug-in, what is another way to run it on Ubuntu.

Comment: The project has been forked and an update released https://github.com/prikhi/pencil

Comment: Pencil works pretty well, they even have a Material UI components library addon

Answer (score 11):

As was mentioned above [WireframeSketcher wireframing tool](http://wireframesketcher.com) is also available on Ubuntu. Recently I started providing a standalone version so it's not Eclipse only anymore. Give it a try.

[image: Sample WireframeSketcher mockup]

Comment: Good program but is a trial: "WireframeSketcher is available as a free trial" with a watermark in exported files. :(

Comment: Export using screen capture tool ;)

Comment: Is that Comic Sans?

Answer (score 3):

I see you mention "internet sites". For web interface mockups, I like to use [gomockingbird.com](https://gomockingbird.com/).

It's very quick and web-based, so it will definitely work in Ubuntu. You could probably use it for software application interface development, as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are a professional and looking for professional application then you can try [balsamiq](https://balsamiq.com/)

Download the desktop app for windows and install it via wine.

It has a 30 day trial period after which you have to buy its license with $89.

According to me it is the best one in the market.

Comment: "_According to me it is the best one in the market._" I like that

Answer (score 1):

Currently **Balsamiq** is the widely used program for mock ups etc in the cooperate levels. It is **professional**.

They have an **trial version** which you can download and play with. It is **not** **FREE**.

https://balsamiq.com/products/

If you are looking for an **open-source** GUI prototyping tool **Pencil** **Project** is recommended. It is **FREE**.

https://pencil.evolus.vn/

It works on `Fedora`, `Ubuntu`, `Windows` and `Mac OSX`.

Find the download page of Pencil Project.

https://pencil.evolus.vn/Downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with Pencil, it's a good program, but I couldn't get any export function to work and I didn't like the program starting a firefox process. In the other hand, I also tried balsamiq mockups, really nice program as well but I ended up sick because they use Adobe Air to make the program available for all platforms, and you already know that Adobe Air doesn't support Linux anymore. Finally I tried Wireframesketcher, I installed it in a few seconds, with an integrated Ubuntu inferface. It's very intuitive and it has got all the features I was looking for. Very powerful program.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `Inkscape` to create a few shapes and be very flexible. Just need to get the basics of Inkscape geometry stuff down for precise positioning of elements and you're good to go, almost unlimited possibilities. Once you've created a nice little palette, you just copy paste and align elements. Whenever you need something new, it's usually not too hard to add.