# What software was used to make the Software Center mockups?

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, design

I was reading this [Ubuntu Software Center design document](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter) and wondering, what software was used to design all those ui concept?

Comment: See also [Native, FOSS GUI prototyping tools?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1763/native-foss-gui-prototyping-tools)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those specific designs are made by hand by [Matthew Paul Thomas](https://launchpad.net/~mpt) on graph paper.

Comment: ah see, that's why it look more natural.

Answer (score 6):

I've found [Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn) to be most valuable when I need to pump out quick little UI mocks. It's a Firefox extension by default but you can also get a version that runs on XUL (the framework beneathe Firefox).

While it might not be what was used for this example, it's worth a look.

Comment: yeah, I did use pencil (the downloaded version).

Answer (score 2):

Mark Shuttleworth uses [Balsamiq Mockups](http://balsamiq.com/products/mockups) for his mockups (like the  [Window Indicators](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/333) one). It's not free though.

[image]

Comment: There is a web demo version of Balsamiq Mockups at: http://builds.balsamiq.com/b/mockups-web-demo/

Answer (score 2):

[Balsamiq Mockups](http://balsamiq.com/products/mockups) is an application that occasionally gets used by Mark and the design team.

It's not free but it is cross-platform (through Java) and provides a lot more features than Pencil.

Comment: Balsamiq is excellent. Though isn't it based on AIR?

Comment: Yes, Balsamiq mockups runs on top of Adobe AIR and not Java.

Adobe AIR does work okay on Ubuntu, at least since Ubuntu 9.10

Answer (score 0):

[WireframeSketcher](http://wireframesketcher.com) lets you do this kind of mockup. You can use it as a standalone tool but also as a plugin for Eclipse-based IDEs (like Aptana and Zend Studio).

[image: Ubuntu Software Center Mockup]

Comment: For the benefit of the reader: this is **$75** for a single license (You should really get other people to recommend your software by the way) :P

Comment: I also give away free licenses to open-source developers and all kinds of do-gooders.