# Sketchy UI used in Ubuntu documentation?

Tags: gui

I'm looking for the software used to create the UI mockups in Ubuntu's documentation, for example, here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareUpdates

Thanks.

[image]

---

**Edit:** The replies I got here are a bit off mark. I do agree, though, that my question is a duplicate. I eventually found the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/14634/240865

Answer (score 0):

Feel your question's title is misleading. You are asking about the tool used to build GUI wireframes. So you can get your answer in any of the links [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=gui%20wireframe%20tool).

My personal favorite is [Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already familiar with Pencil. I asked about a specific tool (see the question's tags).