# How to draw diagrams for git workflow?

Tags: vector-drawings

I want to make some workflow graphics. Is there a convenient tool for that?

I found some Git workflow diagrams in Vincent Driessen's [Successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) and [Jussi Judin's blog post in response](https://barro.github.io/2016/02/a-succesful-git-branching-model-considered-harmful/). I'll paste in just a small chunk of Driessen's drawing here to give you an idea what I'm looking for:

[image: Top quarter of Driessen's Git Graph]

I want to create new lovely "cartoonish" drawings of that sort for a project report.  I like that they have somewhat "fuzzy" text boxes, pleasant callout shapes with configurable pointers to dots, and colored dots.  I wish the editor would make it convenient to re-align pieces. It would be nice if arrows might "move with the dots" to which they point in an "easy" to adjust way.

Can you tell me how it can be done in Ubuntu?  I'm aware of dia, which makes less jazzy illustrations.

Please don't say I need a Microsoft Surface to do this :)

Comment: You could probably make something similar in [LibreOffice Draw](https://smacak.wordpress.com/2011/01/26/opensource-alternative-to-microsoft-visio/)

Comment: You need a Microsoft Surface to do this... Just kidding. This is less of an Ubuntu question and more of a question for something more generic. (Debian, perhaps?) It could be better on some forum where people can give their own input on software they use. Once you find something that might work for you, you just need to check if it's in the archives or figure out some other way of installing it. Either way, this is largely opinion-based.

Comment: Some options are listed here https://askubuntu.com/a/24843/694267

Comment: I contacted Vincent Driessen and he said Apple Keynote was used to make those drawings.  He added an update at the very bottom of the post about it.